# How to set timeout for std::net::UdpSocket?

Tags: sockets, rust

[std::old_io::net::udp::UdpSocket](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/old_io/net/udp/struct.UdpSocket.html) has been replaced with [std::net::UdpSocket](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html), and `fn set_timeout(&mut self, timeout_ms: Option<u64>)` has no equivalent.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to set timeout on any network operations in `std::net` right now. There is an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1047) on that, so for Rust 1.0 it will definitely be fixed. Stay tuned!

In the meantime you can use [`AsRawFd`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html) implementation which each socket has and call low-level socket functions on the file descriptor manually. [`AsRawFd::as_raw_fd()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html#method.as_raw_fd) returns raw file descriptor which represents the underlying socket in the operating system. You can call various low-level socket functions on this file descriptor, like `setsockopt`. These functions are available through `libc` crate. You can find how it could be done in `libstd` sources, for example, [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3cac76bcf239c5db7d612eea52dd39be6e0281b4/src/libstd/sys/common/net.rs#L125). You would also probably want to use `libc` from crates.io - the built-in one is behind a feature gate and hence not available in beta.

In order to set send/read timeout you would need to call `setsockopt` with `SO_SNDTIMEO`/`SO_RCVTIMEO` option, providing a pointer to a [`timeval`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/libc/types/os/common/posix01/struct.timeval.html) instance. This is essentially how it could be done in C. I could expand on this later (in a few hours, probably) if you want.

Comment: Hope `std::net` to be stable soon. Could you explain how to use `AsRawFd`? Thank you.